# Advanced objects as value of Enum

Tags: c#, enums

Is there a way to do something like:

```
public class Test { public int num; public string name;}

public enum MyEnum
{
    Foo = new Test(){ num = 1, name = "hi" }, 
    Bar = new Test() { num = 2, name = "Cool" },
}
```

So that i can do something like:

```
string s = MyEnum.Foo.name;
int i = MyEnum.Bar.num;
```

Basically, i have a large list of items that i don't feel like need their own class. And i like being able to reference a type directly from a enum. (which i can enumerate over)

***** EDIT: *****

Despite the large number of people saying it isn't possible, i was able to get the desired functionality (see selected answer below)

Comment: Enum don't give you his flexibility.

Comment: No, it don't even allow that also. `Foo = new Test()` throws error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Test' to 'int'`

Comment: I found a way to do this with extension methods and attributes. 

(see answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible to get the desired functionality by using Attributes and Extension methods.
First create an Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestAttribute(int num, string name)
    {
        Num = num;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Num { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Then annotate the "advanced" Enum type:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Test(1, "hi")]
    Foo,
    [Test(2, "cool")]
    Bar,
}
```

Then create Extensions for the Advanced Enum:

```
public static class TestExtensions
{

    public static int Num(this MyEnum val)
    {
        int n = 0;
        FieldInfo fi = val.GetType().GetField(val.ToString());
        TestAttribute[] attrs =
        fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute),
                               false) as TestAttribute[];
        if (attrs.Length > 0)
        {
            n = attrs[0].Num;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static string Name(this MyEnum val)
    {
        string n = "";
        FieldInfo fi = val.GetType().GetField(val.ToString());
        TestAttribute[] attrs =
        fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute),
                               false) as TestAttribute[];
        if (attrs.Length > 0)
        {
            n = attrs[0].Name;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static string Title(this MyEnum val)
    {
        return Enum.GetName(val.GetType(), val);
    }

}
```

Then use the enum:

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyEnum.Bar.Name());

        foreach(MyEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
        {
            EnumTest(e);
        }           
    }


    public static void EnumTest(MyEnum e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
           String.Format("{0}'s name={1}: num={2}", e.Title(), e.Name(), e.Num()));
    }
}
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, since an `enum` in C# is a thin abstraction on top of primitive integers. However, you can use the "enum pattern", which is essentially how Java implements enums:

```
public sealed class MyTestEnum
{
    public int Num { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private MyTestEnum(int num, string name)
    {
        Num = num;
        Name = name;
    }

    public static readonly Foo = new MyTestEnum(1, "hi");
    public static readonly Bar = new MyTestEnum(2, "cool");
}
```

Note that the private constructor ensures that the only instances of the class are the `static readonly` instances you create from within the class definition itself. This also makes it safe to compare instances of your enum class with `==` without implementing `operator==` or `Equals()`. Note, though, that a `MyTestEnum` variable may be `null`, as opposed to what a regular enum variable could.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck on using an enum, you can specify the underlying enum type in the definition:

```
public enum MyEnum :int
{
    hi =1,
    Cool =2
}

public class test
{
    public void hello()
    {
        var e = MyEnum.Cool;
        var intValue = (int)e;
        var stringValue = e.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: that only works for byte/int/long/etc... primitive types only.